# Rotation of a line using a rotation matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, rotations

I'm trying to rotate a $100 \times 50$ matrix, $A$. I understood I should be able to do this with a $50 \times 50$ rotation matrix $B$, and that the other $50$ would still be rotated the correct amount, by dot multiplying $AB$ - so, Q.1. is this correct?

$B$ is a $U$ matrix from SVD as my rotation matrix - as it is orthonormal, with a determinant of $-1$, I assumed I could use this as a rotation matrix - Q.2. is this correct?

I have tried adding $-1$ at the top left corner of each matrix in case it mattered that $B$'s determinant was $-1$ instead of $1$, but it didn't help this problem

$A$, if it were $100 \times 100$, would be a $100 \times 100$ identity matrix with only row $1$ and column $1$ of entries - the row and column are the same. I have put a straight line in there for now. Here is a graph of $A$:

[image]

When I rotate by $B$, the line is no longer aligned after row $50$:
e.g. column $1$:
[image]
column 2:
[image]

etc.

It looks like the line at row $50$ just takes something like the average value of all the others. I would like it to follow the trend of the line prior to this point, instead.
Is there a better way of doing this? Is what I'm trying to do impossible?

Comment: 1. How do you graph a matrix? It is completely unclear what any of the graphs mean. 2. We don't put a dot between matrices for matrix multiplication. 3. You can't multiply a $50\times100$ matrix by a $50\times50$ matrix on the right. Put the $50\times50$ matrix on the left.

Comment: The first graph is of all of the columns of matrix $A$.
The second and third graphs are examples of two of the columns after the rotation.

Comment: This just seems like a 2D rotation the way you are describing things. A 50X50 matrix is acting in the wrong number of dimensions.

Comment: You can also see $A$ as the rotation matrix if that helps, they are both U matrices. But I do need 50 x 100 columns in the end.

Comment: $A$ cannot be a $U$ matrix because it is not square. I strongly suspect you are not asking the question you need to ask.

Comment: It is a cut off U matrix - it starts as 100 x 100. I have made it 100 x 50 to do the rotation.
Is there a way of phrasing the question which would make it easier? 
I'm not sure why the line is misaligned after the rotation. I need to do something which would make it aligned.

Comment: @DavidK In response to your first comment, standard matrix multiplication is (confusingly) referred to as the "dot product" in the computer science community.